# Images will not display in MultiImageView component

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, xamarin, components

In Xamarin, how can I display images using the `MultiImageView` component from this link: http://components.xamarin.com/view/MultiImageView?

Here is the code that I have from the web page:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);

MultiImageView imageView = new MultiImageView (this);

imageView.LoadImageList(new [] { 
    "http://blog.xamarin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/evolve-badge.png",
    "http://oi50.tinypic.com/dfzo0k.jpg",
    "http://oi49.tinypic.com/kd6fcp.jpg"});

imageView.ImagesLoaded += (sender, e) =>
{   // Loads the first image in the list
    RunOnUiThread(imageView.LoadImage);
};
```

The application compiles, yet no images are shown. Also, there is no error.

Do I have to use a layout?

Can I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding the `MultiImageView` into your UI layout anywhere.

Try adding it into an existing layout (such as a `LinearLayout`) to get this to work:

**Main Activity**

```
// ...
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    var view = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.viewContent);

    MultiImageView imageView = new MultiImageView (this);

    imageView.LoadImageList(new [] { 
        "http://blog.xamarin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/evolve-badge.png",
        "http://oi50.tinypic.com/dfzo0k.jpg",
        "http://oi49.tinypic.com/kd6fcp.jpg"});

    imageView.ImagesLoaded += (sender, e) =>
    {   // Loads the first image in the list
        RunOnUiThread(imageView.LoadImage);
    };

    view.AddView (imageView);
}
// ...
```

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewContent">
</LinearLayout>
```